# Как увеличить размер маркера адреса google map?

Tags: css, wordpress, google-maps-api

Вставил карту google map на сайт, а маркер маленький. Карту вставил блоком . Каким образом маркер можно увеличить?

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m10!1m8!1m3!1d122592.17607016818!2d30.18107081646333!3d48.728180550683426!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sru!2s!4v1526220801034" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Что значит - "карту вставил блоком"? Приведите код вставки, только не как обычно вы делаете - картинкой, а текстом.

Comment: я привожу код картинкой, потому что доступа у меня к нему нет) А карту я взял с гугла

Comment: В dev tools, откуда вы делаете снимки, правой кнопкой на коде->Copy->Copy outer html